# How does facebook store billions of rows of DB data every month?

Tags: php, mysql, performance, facebook

I know that they do use MySql for DB. But my question is, what could they use to store billions of rows of status updates etc. in one table. Do they partrition them ? Or do they have another way to store this huge amount of data?

Comment: Out of curiosity - how come you ask such a question before trying to google the answer? Surely, googling **must** yield results faster. I suggest doing it.

Comment: Yeah, I'm sure that facebook isn't using single databases for everything, more a database per purpose.

Comment: @Michael: I was REALLY trying to go tho google, but I did not find any good informations about how database/table is partrinioned

Comment: how is that? They recently went as far as open-sourcing their infrastructure setup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are likely sharding their data in combination of master-slave replication.

The problem with databases is replication can only take you so far, because writes don't scale nearly as easily as reads. Therefore, writes heavy database servers are generally sharded or functionally partitioned.